# What does 公け mean?

Tags: translation, readings

I am wondering what the reading and meaning of 公け is in the following sentence:

彼女のことが公けになることを好まず、ひそかに離縁しようと決心した。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is pronounced おおやけ (although I've never seen it with け as okurigana -- usually just 公).  It means "publicly/openly", similar to 公的　【こうてき】.

That sentence would translate as　"Not wanting it to be made publicly known to everyone, He/I decided to break up with her in private."

Answer (score 7):

The reading is `おおやけ`. The meaning is 'public'. In this context, the person does not want (the existence of) her / girlfriend to become public.

Comment: Is there a name or description for the practice of choosing to put more 送り仮名 to specify reading? For example, choosing 勝ち気 instead of 勝気? I notice the tendency is to do this more in newer novels.